# How to create a new keyboard layout in the /usr/share/X11/xkb directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

In the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` directory there are various keyboard layouts listed. I made a copy of the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file under the name `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/new_test_layout`.

The symbols corresponding to the keys being pressed are indicated in the file as in the given example:

```
xkb_symbols "basic"{
//other keys
key <AD01> {[q, Q]};
//other keys
};
```

This means that the symbol lowercase q appears when the key AD01 is pressed normally, and uppercase Q appears when the key AD01 is pressed along with shift key. From my understanding, the third symbol listed will appear when the key is pressed along with alt-gr key, and the fourth symbol when it is pressed along with alt-gr and shift both.

I can replace the symbols provided under each key with a symbol of my choice. However, in this file the symbols are not being directly represented as string characters or by their Unicode values. For example in the file there is

```
key <AB10> {[slash, question]};
```

I am very new to Linux, so I am not sure what these are, but I am guessing that they are variables defined in another file. Anyhow `slash` will correspond to the symbol `/` and `question` will correspond to the symbol `?`

In this webpage, there is an example of an `xkb` layout for a Farsi keyboard.

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition/

Here you can see for example,

`key <AD10> {[Arabic_hah, bracketleft, 0x100202c]};`

So the key AD10 (which is the P key in a regular QWERTY keyboard) should give the character ه which is listed as U0647 (ARABIC LETTER HEH) under Unicode. The letter is being referred to as `Arabic_hah`. Where do I find a listing of these names? If I were to simply use U0647 in its place, would it still be recognised in any file within the `xkb` directory? In Urdu there is a letter *choti he*, ہ that looks similar to the Arabic heh, but has a different Unicode listing: U06C1 (ARABIC LETTER HEH GOAL). I do not know the name that is being used for *choti he* in Linux because I cannot find the Urdu keyboard layout anywhere in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` directory, even though the files for Dari (`af`) and Arabic (`ara`) are present.

Will it be sufficient if I were to simply use the Unicode values for all symbols that are supported by Linux in any file within the `xkb` directory?

Comment: You can also use Unicode values instead of mnemonic codes, in the format you wrote, eg "U06C1".

Comment: Related on [ubuntu.se]: [How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)](https://askubuntu.com/q/482678/250300)

Answer (score 0):

The keyboards are (mostly) not according to language but by country. Urdu keyboards are in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pk` (Pakistan) and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in` (India). And there they used unicode hex.

Comment: In general, if I use any Unicode hex symbol will it be recognised in any file within the /xkb/symbols directory? Where are these names like Arabic_hah for ه defined?

Comment: Yes, you can use unicode hex in pattern UXXXX or 0x100XXXX . Symbols like  Arabic_hah are declared in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` as mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101410

Comment: Okay, thank you. I found the listings of the names of the Urdu-specific characters being mapped to their Unicode values in the keysymdef.h file, including the Urdu numeral symbols (Arabic-Indic digits) which are otherwise absent from my regular Urdu Phonetic keyboard.